# Auto hotkey - Splitting String and checking for numeric values

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a fairly new developer and i have run into a problem.

I'm using auto hotkey to automate at longer manual process, and one of the things i'm trying to do is split an address, and then use each individual part of that address in another system. The problem is that addresses can be very different.

I use `Strsplit` on the entire address, and then i want to check if each part of that address is numerical or a letter.

My problem is that no matter what i try. I always get the same result.

I use "if var is not type" and "if var is type". The problem is that not matter I check for alpha, integer, number or float it always returns true even if the variable is clearly a string and I check for numbers. Sample code below.

```
xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")

Array := StrSplit(xl.Range("C2").text, A_Space, ",")

if Array[1] is not number
{
    Msgbox, False
}


if Array[1] is number
{
    Msgbox, True
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an array element use the := operator:

```
xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
Array := StrSplit(xl.Range("C2").text, A_Space, ",")
element1 := Array[1]
; MsgBox, % element1
if element1 is not number
    Msgbox, False
if element1 is number
    Msgbox, True
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that out.